# Computing mean for every 5 elements column wise

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have an array of shape (10,12). I want the mean of first 5 elements column wise .I know we can use mean (axis=0) but this goes over the entire column and not 5 elements only. Is there any way to get the mean of only five elements column wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
# sample data:
a = np.arange(120).reshape(10,12)

a[:,:5].mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([  2.,  14.,  26.,  38.,  50.,  62.,  74.,  86.,  98., 110.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Slice the array like this:

```
print(arr[:,:5].mean(axis=1))
```

An array slicing syntax is `arr[cols,rows]`, and small mistake is axis, 1 goes row-wise